# Порты. Локальные и внешние?

Tags: алгоритм, сеть, tcp

Изучал компьютерные сети. Попал в тупик...
Некоторые мучаются с закрытыми портами, при использование каких-либо программ (uTorrent, skype)

Приведу пример псевдокода, который разворачивает простой tcp-сервер:

```
s = socket()
s.bind('localhost', 3333)
s.listen(3)
```

Как я понял, этот код разворачивает сервер только на локальном хосте (?!) Как же тогда программа устанавливает соединение с сервером? Как же она пересылает данные?

Сервер, находящийся в сотни километров, не сможет же отправить данные по адресу `123.123.123.123:3333`??
Если `ip` клиента (программы) не является выделенным и провайдер не разрешает открывать порты??!

Я вот проверил, у `skype` нет открытых портов на моем внешнем `ip`..
Получается, что порты бывают внутренние и внешние??

Comment: Порт это всего лишь номер (который передается вместе с вашими данными), по которому операционка определяет какому приложению его направить.

Comment: > Как я понял, этот код разворачивает сервер только на локальном хосте (?!) Как же тогда программа устанавливает соединение с сервером? Как же она пересылает данные? В смысле? Подключается к серверу по ip и порту и пересылает данные, как обычно.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Некоторые мучаются с закрытыми портами, при использование каких-либо программ (uTorrent, skype)

Термин "закрытый порт" в данном случае - ошибочен.

Либо порт запрещён (настройки антивируса/файрвола не позволяют сформировать сокет, прослушивающий этот порт, т.е. принимающий пакеты, приходящие на этот порт), либо занят (сокет, прослушивающий этот порт, уже сформирован другим процессом, а это ресурс неразделяемый). Впрочем, запрет организован именно как занятость, хотя в действительности порт не занят.

"Внутренних" и "внешних" портов не существует. Существует локальный порт (на этом хосте) и удалённый порт (на хосте, с которым ведётся сетевой обмен).

**UPD:** "Закрытый порт" - это когда приложение смогло сформировать прослушивающий сокет, но все пакеты, приходящие на этот порт, перехватываются (и дропаются) брэндмауэром/антивирусом.

Comment: например, я отдал другу написанный эхо-сервер (udp), он запустил... я отправляю ему запрос, на его внешний `ip` и порт `3333` (`123.123.123.123:3333`)... при этом, его ip не является выделенным, он обычный юзер на винде. мой запрос дойдет?

Comment: `его ip не является выделенным` - расшифруйте. `он обычный юзер на винде` - а это к чему? намёк, что он ламер? `я отправляю ему запрос, на его внешний ip` - то есть у него "серый" адрес и подключение через NAT или прокси? и при этом не приобретена услуга "белого" адреса? конечно, не дойдёт.

Comment: `его ip не является выделенным - его ip не является белым`. Спасибо. А как тогда работает сеть `p2p`, если взять `skype`, например?

Comment: p2p-сеть использует внешний сервер (третий узел) с "белым" адресом. Как минимум для инициации соединения, но чаще в течение всего сеанса обмена. Т.е. каждый их конечных узлов общается с сервером, а тот ретранслирует поток второму конечному узлу. И обратно.